# Is there a way to call the TouchUpInside action in a custom UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm writing a custom `UIButton` for my app. However, I want to add a complete action to the button. This way I can return a `BOOL` from the action and then execute some code in the button (ie. display an animation) and then call the completion method.

So, ideally, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
[button addAction:^(){
    NSLog(@"Action!");
    return true;
} completion:^() {
    NSLog(@"Completion!");
    return true;
} forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

How do I override what happens when `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` occurs? Or another controlevent for that matter.

Comment: The information you need is in `UIControl` reference/programming guides. It's not specific to `UIButton`. Apple's search sucks right now, so I can't find/paste anything quickly, but that'll point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by doing some like:

CustomButton.h

```
@interface CustomButton : UIButton
- (void)addAction:(void (^)(CustomButton *button))action onCompletion:(void (^)(CustomButton *button))completion forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)event;
@end
```

CustomButton.m

```
#import "CustomButton.h"

@interface CustomButton ()

@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^actionHandler)(CustomButton *button);
@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^completionHandler)(CustomButton *button);

@end

@implementation CustomButton

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
}
*/



- (void)addAction:(void (^)(CustomButton *button))action onCompletion:(void (^)(CustomButton *button))completion forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)event
{
    self.actionHandler = action;
    self.completionHandler = completion;

    __weak __typeof__(self) weakSelf = self;
    [self addTarget:weakSelf action:@selector(buttonAction) forControlEvents:event];
}

- (void)buttonAction
{
    if (self.actionHandler) {
        self.actionHandler(self);
    }

    // This will execute right after executing action handler.
    // NOTE: If action handler is dispatching task, then execution of completionHandler will not wait for completion of dispatched task
    //       that should handled using some notification/kvo.
    if (self.completionHandler) {
        self.completionHandler(self);
    }
}


@end
```